# Using DataAnnotation's on POCO and reflecting results using MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, ef-code-first

I have been looking into `DataAnnotations` and creating my own `DataAnnotations` for future use - mainly in MVC4 (which is fairly easy it's safe to say). I want to verify how useful, effective and easy to use they will be if I use the same `Model` classes in a WPF project.

```
public class Customer
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [Required()]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class ViewModelBase : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  //... (INotifyPropertyChanged)
  public string Error
  {
    get 
    {
      return string.Empty;
    }
  }
  public string this[string columnName]
  {
    get
    {
      //According to tutorials, something here
      return string.Empty;
    }
  }
}
```

So if I were to move on to creating a `CustomerViewModel` which inherits from the base class, would I have to present a subset view of the model properties like:

```
public class CustomerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Meaning I have to implement the annotations again, or is it possible to just use the model and somehow reflect model validation back to the front end using **WPF's MAGICAL binding**?

I have been looking at numerous articles, but none of which seem to be neat or very consice - such as:

http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/04/27/wpf-data-validation-using-dataannotations/

Answer (score 0):

Why would you put another Name property in your viemodel?

If you have a Customer property in your viewmodel, you can access it in you xaml like:

`{Binding Customer.Name}`

This will automatically take your dataanotations from your model class.

Edit: For a good example see: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98681/Validating-User-Input-WPF-MVVM